# Is there a way to disable squash and merge for certain branches in GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I am trying to find a tool that would help disable squash and merge for certain branches, but not all of them.

Github settings is allowing me to disable squash and merge, but it applies for all the branches, and the protected branches area does not have an option to limit merge options.

Thank you!

Comment: were you able to figure out a solution for this @paxcow

Comment: What exactly is your use-case?

Comment: @knittl Not OP but my use case is: 'staging' as the default branch, and 'main' as the release branch -- want feature branches to be squash merged to staging, and staging to only be merged via merge commit to main. Any ideas?

Comment: @KyleChadha I'll repeat the same answer that I have already posted below as an answer: it's not possible in GitHub, at least I don't know of any such functionality. You can create a feature request and they might implement it

Comment: We have the same problem with our release process: a release branch named release-* has a commit with a tag like 0.84.0 and we want this tag to persist after merging. This requires preserving the commits. However, feature branches are normally squashed into one commit and this is our default.

Comment: A possible improvement for GitHub would be to warn us if we're about to squash or rebase a branch with tags (although rebasing could move the tag intelligently).

Answer (score 9):

No, to the best of my knowledge, that's not possible with GitHub. You could create a feature request for them and they might implement it.

Comment: There is a feature request
https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/10809
Please upvote so that it gets more traction .

Answer (score 4):

I've been working on an extension that solves this problem.

[Link to Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-sm-blocker/aabhjeaepficccegjneggegjjcegnhel).

It allows defining a set of branches (using regex) to disable the "Squash and Merge" button.

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

Please let me know if you have any issues or feedback.

Answer (score 2):

So far (June 2023), no clear solution, as [discussed in this GitHub thread 10809](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/10809).

The [latest suggestion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/10809#discussioncomment-6110392) from [Ivan Degtiarenko](https://github.com/ivan-degtiarenko):

> I ended up creating Tampermonkey script that allows you to disable certain merge options on specified branch names: [`disable-merge-options-github-branches.js`](https://gist.github.com/ivan-degtiarenko/1e7a63671ff7db28dc07ac4b3750ec12).
> It requires you to adjust branch names and repo in the script.

Note that this script only changes the UI, so you wouldn't accidentally press the wrong button. I think it's still possible to merge using the wrong option via API.

---

In the context of "[Pull request merge queue (public beta)](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-02-08-pull-request-merge-queue-public-beta/)" (Feb. 2023), you can also [specify merge types for the merge queue](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/10809#discussioncomment-4935615).
Set up the branch protection rules like this:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/83613150/221994741-cfc18928-90fd-47d9-8b94-511ed0ffefde.png]